# Getting an express MIME error when I try to load css stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, web-development-server

I keep getting the following MIME error while trying to lead in a stylesheet to my application:
[image]

I have followed the newest issues on this MIME error for hours now with no luck. I have told my Express development server to pull resource from a static file and still no luck. Here is my development hierarchy:

[image]

I will include my code below. Any help is appreciated.

```
**index.html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="subject" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/styles/customStyles.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Clone Application</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="conatiner-fluid">

        <nav class="nav-wrapper">
            Hello Again
        </nav>

        Hello World
    </div>

    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
**Server.js**
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = require("./router");
const path = require("path");

const PORT = 3000; 

app.use(router, express.static('public'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port: " + PORT);
});
```

```
**router.js**
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const pages = "/public/pages/";

router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/pages/home/index.html")
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML links to the stylesheet at `/public/styles/customStyles.css`

However, the correct URI is `/styles/customStyles.css` (or preferably without the first slash, `styles/customStyles.css` so it will continue to work if the page isn't in the root).

`app.use(router, express.static('public'));` tells express to serve static files under the 'public' folder, so adding 'public' to your CSS URI is incorrect.

You're getting an HTML MIME type due to the Express default error page ('Cannot GET..')

Comment: Huge brain fart on my part. Thanks for this!